# MS Excel Time Format (Not Function)

Tags: excel, time, customization

I am having a problem with Excel's time format. I am trying to log amount of time spent on things. (and i want to be lazy) I try logging the time and excel converts it to a date. I know why it does this, but not how to stop it. I have even tried a custom format so that excel wont convert it, but excel somehow overrides my customization. Im trying to log four minutes and 24 seconds. i have tried doing 00424, 000424, 424, and a few others. I have tried 4:24 and excel changes that to 24:00. like i said, i have tried customization and i have tried pre-made formats, but nothing fixes it. Preferably i'd like to be lazy and just type in 424 and have it converted to 4:24. Any help? 
Thanks, Greg

Answer (score 0):

Use two columns, A where you enter values, B where you display them.

In B1 and below put:

```
=(INT(A1/100)*60+MOD(A1,100))/60/60/24
```

Then format column B as custom `M:SS`

Answer (score 0):

Change the formatting of the cell to "Text" .. then type whatever you want: ie "4:24", "424", "0424", etc all work.  No fancy formatting, but the data is in.  Next, take the next cell and parse/format it (again in text) the way you want:  So if you're input is simply "424" (in A1) as you want ... just do a:  =concatenate(mid(a1,1,len(a1)-2),":",mid(a1,len(a1)-1,2))